# jQuery Ajax request from path String

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I'm working on a local and staging site.  The local site is served with `http://` protocol, while the staging site is served with `https://` protocol.

I am using ajax in my site.  My code is something like this:

```
var str='api/callback/this/one/here';
$.get(str);
...
```

Works fine on the local site.  On the staging site, I get `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://currentpage' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api-request'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

But if I make the request using `https`, it works fine.  Our backend doesn't care about the protocol.  It'll return it no matter what.

The weird thing:  If, from the developer console, I type `$.get('//request/path/here')`, it works fine.  Chrome automatically converts it to the proper protocol, which is what I would expect to happen.

Why won't my source code adapt?  There is no explicit protocol used anywhere in my source code - not even in the accompanying HTML.  I can work around by using `location.protocol + ajaxString`, but that seems just the same as not doing anything.  It's not any more secure - or it shouldn't be.

Any insight?

Comment: Do you have a `<base />` tag in your HTML with HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Comment: @Justastudent - no - I found that answer on the site, and I was excited - but alas  - it doesn't apply here.